# Mockito and this calls

Tags: mockito

I have this very simple example as follows:

```
public class Foo {
    public int foo() {
        return foo1();
    }
    public int foo1() {
        return 1;
    }
}

public class FooTest {
    @Test public void testFoo() {
        Foo f = mock(Foo.class);
        doReturn(1000).when(f).foo1();
        assertThat(f.foo(), equalTo(1000));
    }
}
```

I'm getting a java.lang.AssertionError: Expected: is(1000) got: <0>, and I don't understand why. Obviously I must be doing something wrong, as this is very basic mocking, so I can't imagine this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a spy instead of a mock.

http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13

Try this

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
Foo f = spy(foo);
```

Comment: Tom, welcome to Stack Overflow.  If this answer is what you were looking for, then the appropriate way to indicate that is by clicking the little tick to the left hand side of the answer.  Other people who are contemplating providing an answer can then see on the list of questions, that YOUR question already HAS an answer that is acceptable to you.  It also rewards user2003273 appropriately for providing such a nice answer.

Comment: David, thanks for the clarififcation. I tried upvoting, but as a new user I was not allowed.

Answer (score 3):

Note that you recorded the expectation on `foo1()`, but then called `foo()` later... So of course, it returns `0`, not `1000`.

Comment: Since foo1 is stubbed to return 1000, and foo calls foo1, why does foo return 0 and not 1000?

Comment: Because when you mock a class, *all* of its methods are mocked. Unless the test explicitly specifies otherwise for a given method (like `foo1` here), any non-void method in the mocked class will return the default value for its return type (in this case, `0` for `int`).

Answer (score 0):

By the time CGLIB has gotten hold of your `Foo` class it doesn't care about what clever implementation you have underlying. Your return statement is not considered. Mockito sees (1) a mocked class called Foo, (2) an instruction when foo1() is invoked and (3) no instructions when foo() is invoked.

On a stylistic note isn't *when* preferred over doReturn now? So;

```
when(f.foo1()).thenReturn(1000);
```

Comment: Re your stylistic note - I don't see any reason to prefer `when...thenReturn` over `doReturn...when`.  Quite the opposite.  The latter can be used for void methods, spies, methods that have already been stubbed, and so on.  So if you use `doReturn...when` consistently, you never need to learn a second syntax.  On the other hand, if you learn `when...thenReturn` first, then before long, you'll find yourself needing `doReturn...when` anyway.  Better just to learn the `doReturn...when` syntax and forget about the other.

Comment: Thanks for your comment David. I use a variety of other constructs in order to mock void methods (doAnswer etc) and to-date never needed a doReturn...sounds like I've been making life more difficult for myself. :S

Comment: Having read the [docs](http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.5/javadoc/org/mockito/Mockito.html#doReturn(java.lang.Object)) they say its an 'elegant' construct but its pure use case is when you **can't** properly mock a class. Ending up in this scenario when considering non-legacy and non-3rd party code is a bad thing and probably points to class design issues. This is probably why we so rarely use this functionality as we are warned far away from partial mocks except for legacy and third party code.

Comment: Right, I do admit that the `when...thenReturn` construction does do some type checking that `doReturn` doesn't.  But if you mess up the types, you will find out pretty soon when you run the test, so I don't consider this particularly valuable.  The most common case where you MUST use `doReturn` is with void methods.